# Must declare the scalar variable error for stored procedure in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nopcommerce, scalar, sql-query-store

I want to search **GTIN** option in admin product list. So, for that I am providing GTIN value in **ProductLoadAllPaged** store procedure. Now, when I search GTIN value from product list at that time throw datatable error and from console application get message that **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@GTIN".**.

Here is store procedure added code,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductLoadAllPaged]
(
    @GTIN nvarchar(50) = null--AWAZ
)
AS
BEGIN   
    ...........
    
    --SKU (exact match)
    IF @SearchSku = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + 'OR p.[Sku] = @OriginalKeywords '
    END

    --NEW ADDED CODE FOR GTIN SEARCH
    IF @GTIN is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + 'AND p.Gtin = @GTIN'
    END

    --localized product name
    SET @sql = @sql + '
    UNION
    SELECT lp.EntityId
    FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
        AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
        AND ( (lp.LocaleKey = N''Name'''
        
    ..........
END
```

Comment: It's not shown in the extract you've included, but at a guess the stored procedure executes `@sql` using `sp_executesql`. You need to add `@GITN` to the list of parameters accepted by the call to (parameter 2 of `sp_executesql`) and pass its value to the call (parameter 3 of `sp_executesql`). Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @EdHarper CAN YOU SHOW ME CODE LIKE THAT?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-executing-a-simple-select-statement - if this is how the code is executed already, then there should be an example inside the stored procedure definition.

Answer (score 1):

In the stored procedure change this line of code:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Keywords nvarchar(4000), @OriginalKeywords nvarchar(4000)', @Keywords, @OriginalKeywords
```

To this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Keywords nvarchar(4000), @OriginalKeywords nvarchar(4000), @GTIN nvarchar(50)', @Keywords, @OriginalKeywords, @GTIN
```

This will add your new parameter when executing the dynamic SQL query.